# How to loop retrieved much data in view (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, view

how to retrieve much data in view (codeigniter) using while(). if I use foreach, I can't get the desired result. this is my code:

//my view home.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#check').click(function(event){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            var form_data = {
                                name: "xxxx"
                            };

                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'http://localhost:8000/jqjx/index.php/cont/getname',
                                type: 'POST',
                                async : false,
                                data: form_data,
                                dataType: 'html',
                                success: function(resp){

                                    $('#content').html(resp);                                       
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                    }); 
                });
```

//my controller cont.php

```
public function getname()
                {
                       $data = array();
                    $namex = $this->input->post('name');
                    if($q = $this->my_model->detail_data($namex))
                    {
                      $data['data_detail'] = $q;
                      $this->load->view('tamp_page', $data);
                    }
                }
```

my helper page (view) tamp_page.php

```
 <?php
                        if(isset($data_detail))
                        {
                            foreach ($data_detailas $row) {
                                echo $row['name']."<br/>";
                                echo $row['birthday']."<br/>";
                            }

                        }
                    ?>
```

if I use :

```
<?php
                        if(isset($data_detail))
                        {
                           echo $name_data['id_transactions'] . "<br/>";
                           echo $name_data['goods'] . "<br/>";
                        }
                    ?>
```

it's still work but just for 1 data result. so how I can loop more much data.. thanks..

Comment: You are sending just 1 name -> you are getting only 1 name. Edit the question and write the result you expect.

Comment: it's just the example..

Comment: this question already answered. where is your database question?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(isset($data_detail))
{
   foreach ($data_detail as $row) 
   {
      echo $row['name']."<br/>"; //$row['name] was not properly closed. single quote(') was missing
      echo $row['birthday']."<br/>";
   }

}
?>
```

Comment: no, already edited. I use that code, but the desired result is missing, just show the first character.

Comment: can you paste here what is the expected output and what your getting

Comment: If the solution solves your problem, could you accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just basic use of `foreach`:

```
if(isset($data_detail)){
  foreach ($data_detailas as $row) {
    echo $row['name'] . "<br/>";
    echo $row['birthday'] . "<br/>";
  }
}
```